# oauth2 get a list of scopes from access token

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

Is it possible to get a list of scopes from an access token?

e.g.

```
$token = 'ab12..'
$scopes = tokenToScopes($token)
```

// --> $scopes = ['address', 'subscriptions',...]

Comment: @chandlerbing how do you know their access token was created via googles authentication server?  That's not going to help if it isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can depend upon the access token.  If its a Jwt you can just decode it you can test it by using using [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/).   A lot of auth servers also have a tokeninfo endpoint which will give you information on your token.  This will depend upon the auth server you are using.

```
{
  "nbf": 1514888070,
  "exp": 1514891670,
  "iss": "http://localhost:5000",
  "aud": [
    "http://localhost:5000/resources",
    "testapi"
  ],
  "client_id": "testclient",
  "sub": "21248582",
  "auth_time": 1514882023,
  "idp": "Google",
  "supporter": "21248582",
  "name": "Xxxxx",
  "application_id": "14055160",
  "scope": [
    "openid",
    "profile",
    "email",
    "testapi"
  ],
  "amr": [
    "external"
  ]
}
```